# different logins access different data from tables

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-design, web-applications, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using MVC 3, and mssql 2008 r2 and,
I was wondering if there is an automated mechanism that associates different logins to different data from database tables.

For example I want to create a calendar. But I want each user to view only his own entries. So I have a table Appointment with time and place. But I do not want to include an association from LDAP because I will need to do that in a number of places.

Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not planning to do this in the application logic, then the only way I can currently think of to do this is through the use of stored procedures or table valued functions.

What you would do is create what are often referred to as CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) stored procedures for the tables. Obviously if you are only reading from the table(s), then only a read sproc is needed.

Within the stored procedure, you can put in logic to filter the results based on the user's login.

You can assign the user to a role in the database and give that role execute privilege on the stored procedure. Or if you are using a table value function, you would give the role SELECT privilege on the function. You would not give the user any privileges to view the table itself.

Ex.

```
    CREATE ROLE CalendarReader AUTHORIZATION dbo;
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE Calendar_Get
    AS
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       SELECT 
           EventDate
          ,EventText
       FROM 
           Calendar
       WHERE 
           UserLogin = suser_sname()
       ;
    GO

    GRANT EXECUTE ON Calendar_Get TO CalendarReader;
    GO
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing else for it but to have your database be structured in such a way as to know which data belongs to each user.  So your CALENDAR table is going to need a user_id column on it.  If you are using any ASP.NET web-based application framework, including MVC, you have access to the authentication provider that your application uses.

For an MVC application, your controller needs to pass the user ID (i.e. HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) to the data layer, which needs to use this value in the where clause.

Trying to do this implicitly will just get you into trouble.  For example, if you need to have an administrator with access to multiple users' calendars, you can't use an implicit filter.  You need to have your controller tell your data layer what it wants.